# Why does it say the lowest number is Null always?

Tags: java, null, hashmap

Why does it say the lowest number is Null always? Im confused i tried to make a lot of changes but cant see whats wrong with it.

It gives me the correct highest number but for the lowest one it always prints in the console:  Lowest sales were in null

Here is my Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Project5 {

    /**
     * @param args
     *//****************************************************
     * Filename:       jdoe2pg.c                               *
     * Name:           Ima Student                             *
     * SSAN:           6789                                    * 
     * Date:           13 December 2005                        *
     * Course:         CMSC-104                                * 
     * Description:    (Your psuedocode for main() goes here)  *
     *     Analysis:                                           *
     *                 Input:                                  *
     *                 Output:                                 *
     *                 Formulas:                               *
     *                 Constraints:                            *
     *                 Assumptions:                            *
     *     Design:     (Psuedocode is here)                    *
     * Notes:          (As needed, such has how to compile)    *
     ***********************************************************/


    public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static HashMap<Integer, String> Months = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> SALES = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SALES.add(0,000);
        addHash();

        for(int i =1;i<=12;i++){
        System.out.println("Enter sales for " + Months.get(i));
        int value= in.nextInt();
        SALES.add(i,value);
        }

        //Get Max
        int max = Collections.max(SALES);
        int maxIndex = SALES.indexOf(max);
        System.out.println("Highest sales were in " + Months.get(maxIndex));

        //Get Min
        int min = Collections.min(SALES);
        int minIndex = SALES.indexOf(min);
        System.out.println("Lowest sales were in " + Months.get(minIndex));

        //Gets all the sales
        for(int i=1;i<=12;i++){
        System.out.println(Months.get(i) + ": " + SALES.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void addHash(){

        Months.put(1,"January");
        Months.put(2,"Feburary");
        Months.put(3,"March");
        Months.put(4,"April");
        Months.put(5,"May");
        Months.put(6,"June");
        Months.put(7,"July");
        Months.put(8,"August");
        Months.put(9,"September");
        Months.put(10,"October");
        Months.put(11,"November");
        Months.put(12,"December");


    }

}
```

Comment: This implies that `minIndex` was outside the range of [1,12]. Use the debugger to follow your program's flow and see what exactly is going on. Edit: the lowest value in SALES is 0 that you put in via `SALES.add(0,000);`.

Comment: Probably it has something to do with `Months` being **1** indexed.

Comment: Then how did the max work? @Sparta??

Comment: @kryger then how do i fix it :( I basically finished it but dont know how to fix low

Comment: @AmanuelBogale The same as "min" works, but since the lowest value is on index *"0"* and you have no Month connected to that value, the map returns `null` instead.

Comment: @AmanuelBogale remove the "SALES.add(0,000);" line. *"I basically finished it"*: you're checking your program's correctness only when you're "basically finished"? EDIT: ...and then proceed with verifying the rest of your code.

Comment: @kryger This alone won't be enough :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SALES.add(0,000);
```

Your lowest sales are 0 for month 0, which doesn't have a value in your Map.

Therefore `Months.get(minIndex)` returns null.

You don't have to add the 0 value for 0 index.

```
    // SALES.add(0,000); remove this
    addHash();

    for(int i = 0;i< 12;i++){ // iterate from 0 to 11
        System.out.println("Enter sales for " + Months.get(i+1)); // add 1 when you need
                                                                  // to obtain month name
        int value= in.nextInt();
        SALES.add(i,value); // or simply SALES.add(value);
    }

    //Get Max
    int max = Collections.max(SALES);
    int maxIndex = SALES.indexOf(max);
    System.out.println("Highest sales were in " + Months.get(maxIndex+1));

    //Get Min
    int min = Collections.min(SALES);
    int minIndex = SALES.indexOf(min);
    System.out.println("Lowest sales were in " + Months.get(minIndex+1));

    //Gets all the sales
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
        System.out.println(Months.get(i+1) + ": " + SALES.get(i));
    }
```

Of course you can change the keys of your `Months` map to be from 0 to 11, in which case you wouldn't have to add 1 to the index whenever you call `Months.get()`.

Comment: Ok so when i put 0 index high the one that gets the high one becomes null when its null the low one becomes null. What do i do to fix it?

Comment: @AmanuelBogale I don't understand your comment. The code I posted should work. Did you try it?

Comment: Thankyou so MUCH!! Just asking is there like a Collections.Average? Just asking But THANKS

Comment: @AmanuelBogale You can write simple code to calculate the average yourself. If you are using Java 8, you can look into `IntSummaryStatistics` which can be used to get the average (among other things) of an IntStream, but you'll have to learn about Streams.

Comment: Ok Thanks a Bunch @Eran!

Answer (score 1):

Java indexes start at 0.

```
SALES.add(0,000); //remove
```

and change these

```
SALES.add(value);
System.out.println(Months.get(i) + ": " + SALES.get(i - 1));
```

Comment: Thankyou so MUCH!! Just asking is there like a Collections.Average?